# Save numeric in number category using apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I need to store numeric in number category (right click->Catergory=number). I have tried using the below code, but it saves in general format.

```
        String valueAsString = "2345";          
        HSSFCell cellE1 = row1.createCell((short) 4);
        cellE1.setCellValue(new BigDecimal(valueAsString).doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a cell style to the cell, which formats it as you want. Something like

```
Worbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

DataFormat fmts = wb.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat();

// Cell Styles apply to the whole workbook, only create once
CellStyle numericStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
numericStyle.setDataFormat(fmts.getFormat("0")); // Format string

....

// Apply to the cells
Row r = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell c = r.createCell(0); // A1
c.setCellStyle(numericStyle);
c.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble("12345"));
```